# Evolution Mail on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: evolution

There is an option to display user's picture in the message preview.
I would like to change my old photo to some newer one.
I have changed it in every place: Gmail, Gravatar, Wordpress and so on. With no effect.

Where Evolution stores such pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evolution can display contact images in messages, when the options are enabled in *Mail Preferences*, from:

- The *Face* header in the message itself.
- The image in the *Contact* as stored in an address book within Evolution itself.
- The contact's image from Gravatar, if the e-mail used has an associated picture.

Comment: Many thanks, I have found the old image in Evolution's address book and I have changed it there. It works.